# GetJSON Affecting Only Last Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, getjson

I have some movies which I'd like to have posters above them. I tried making a loop for all items and using getJSON with OMDb API to get poster link, but it seem so affect only the last item. I understand JavaScript, but when it comes to jQuery I'm completely lost. I'd appreciate any help.
There's no dumb questions, right? :)

I'll let the code do the rest of the talking...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1232829/" target="_blank"><li><h1>21 Jump Street</h1><h2>2012</h2></li></a>
      <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2294449/" target="_blank"><li><h1>22 Jump Street</h1><h2>2014</h2></li></a>
      <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1637725/" target="_blank"><li><h1>Ted</h1><h2>2012</h2></li></a>
    </ul>   
    <script>
      function appendPosters() {    
        var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for (i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {                        
          var newImg = document.createElement("img");

          lis[i].appendChild(newImg);
          lis[i].insertBefore(lis[i].lastChild, lis[i].firstChild);

          var getA = lis[i].parentElement;
          var imdbLink = getA.getAttribute("href");
          var imdbId = imdbLink.substr(26, 9);
          var getImg = lis[i].firstChild;

          $.getJSON('http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=' + imdbId).then(function(response) {
            var poster = response.Poster;
            getImg.setAttribute("src", poster);
          });
        }
      }    
      appendPosters();
    </script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Please keep in mind that HTML code and variables cannot be changed due to them being a part of other scripts.

Comment: `$.getJSON` is asynchronous. By the time it gets a response from the server and tries to set the `src`, your loop is finished, and `getImg` is the last element. You can use closures to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first issue is that your HTML is invalid. The `a` elements cannot be children of the `ul`. You need to place them inside the `li`.

From there you can use jQuery to loop over the `li` elements, finding the `href` of the `a` within them. I amended the logic to get the IMDB Id to split the value by the `/` which should be a lot more robust. Your current method would easily be broken simply by changing to `https://` URLs. You can then make the request to get the poster URL. Once that completes you can create the new `img` element, setting the `src` as required. Try this:

```js
function appendPosters() {
  $("li").each(function() {
    var $li = $(this);
    var urlArr = $li.find('a').prop('href').split('/');
    var imdbId = urlArr[urlArr.length -2];
    
    $.getJSON('http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=' + imdbId).then(function(response) {
      $li.append('<img src="' + response.Poster + '" />');
    });
  });
}

appendPosters();
```

```html
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1232829/" target="_blank">
      <h1>21 Jump Street</h1>
      <h2>2012</h2>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2294449/" target="_blank">
      <h1>22 Jump Street</h1>
      <h2>2014</h2>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1637725/" target="_blank">
      <h1>Ted</h1>
      <h2>2012</h2>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Works great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Used jquery to iterate the li elements and create image tag.

```
function appendPosters() {
    $('li').each(function () {
        var $handler = $(this);
        var imdbId = $(this).parent().attr('href').substr(26, 9);
        getresponse($handler, $handler.parent().attr('href').substr(26, 9), function (data) {
        });
    });
}

function getresponse($handler, imdbId, callback) {
    $.getJSON('http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=' + imdbId).then(function (response) {
        var poster = response.Poster;
        console.log(poster);
        var img = $('<img>'); //Equivalent: $(document.createElement('img'))
        img.attr('src', poster);
        img.appendTo($handler);
        callback(true);
    });
}
```

Please refer below jsfiddle link to see working demo

https://jsfiddle.net/ganesh2412/bmz7ohx5/